# Error installing rstudio-desktop package on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, rstudio

When I run `yay -R rstudio-desktop` in terminal, the installer goes for a while before hitting this error and exiting.

```
Buildfile: /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/build.xml

i18n-checksum:
     [echo] Commands.cmd.xml i18n checksum matches: true

i18n-unix-check:

i18n-unix:

i18n-windows-check:

i18n-windows:

generate-i18n:

ext:
   [jscomp] Compiling 62 file(s) with 93 extern(s)
   [jscomp] 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

javac:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/bin
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/bin
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Compiling 2591 source files to /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/bin
     [copy] Copying 1883 files to /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/bin

gwtc:

panmirror:
     [echo] yarn location: yarn
     [echo] panmirror location: ./lib/quarto/apps/panmirror
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/www/js/panmirror
     [exec] yarn install v1.22.19
     [exec] [1/4] Resolving packages...
     [exec] [2/4] Fetching packages...
     [exec] warning "eslint-config-custom > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > panmirror > vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js@2.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "vite@>2.0.0-0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > quarto-vscode-editor > vite-plugin-static-copy@0.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "vite@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor-codemirror > @codemirror/autocomplete@6.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "@lezer/common@^1.0.0".
     [exec] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-utils@0.9.6" has incorrect peer dependency "prosemirror-tables@^0.9.1".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > quarto-ojs-runtime > @rollup/plugin-commonjs@22.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "rollup@^2.68.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > quarto-ojs-runtime > @rollup/plugin-node-resolve@13.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rollup@^2.42.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > quarto-vscode-editor > @blueprintjs/core > react-popper@1.3.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > react-dock@0.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "babel-runtime@^6.3.13".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > react-json-tree@0.11.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > react-json-tree@0.11.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > unstated@2.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > quarto-ojs-runtime > @rollup/plugin-commonjs > @rollup/pluginutils@3.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rollup@^1.20.0||^2.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > @emotion/css > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.10.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > unstated > create-react-context@0.1.6" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
     [exec] warning "workspace-aggregator-95c856ef-3bde-4855-b510-451b1a07fa4d > editor > prosemirror-dev-tools > @emotion/css > @emotion/babel-plugin > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.18.6" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
     [exec] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
     [exec] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
     [exec] error /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/packages/build/node_modules/esbuild, /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/apps/lsp/node_modules/esbuild, /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/apps/vscode/node_modules/esbuild: Command failed.
     [exec] Exit code: 1
     [exec] Command: node install.js
     [exec] Arguments: 
     [exec] Directory: /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/apps/vscode/node_modules/esbuild
     [exec] Output:
     [exec] /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/apps/vscode/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:115
     [exec]       } catch {
     [exec]               ^
     [exec] 
     [exec] SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     [exec]     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
     [exec]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
     [exec]     at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
     [exec]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
     [exec]     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
     [exec]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
     [exec]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
     [exec]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
     [exec]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
     [exec]     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
     [exec] info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
     [exec] warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba: Command failed.
     [exec] Exit code: 1
     [exec] Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
     [exec] Arguments: 
     [exec] Directory: /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba
     [exec] Output:
     [exec] node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
     [exec] node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
     [exec] node-pre-gyp info using node@8.17.0 | linux | x64
     [exec] node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release/nodejieba.node\" (not found)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/yanyiwu/nodejieba/releases/download/v2.5.2/nodejieba-v2.5.2-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/yanyiwu/nodejieba/releases/download/v2.5.2/nodejieba-v2.5.2-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz 
     [exec] node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for nodejieba@2.5.2 and node@8.17.0 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
     [exec] node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/yanyiwu/nodejieba/releases/download/v2.5.2/nodejieba-v2.5.2-node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz 
     [exec] gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
     [exec] gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
     [exec] gyp info using node@8.17.0 | linux | x64
     [exec] gyp info ok 
     [exec] gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
     [exec] gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
     [exec] gyp info using node@8.17.0 | linux | x64
     [exec] gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.3 found at \"/usr/bin/python\"
     [exec] gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
     [exec] gyp info spawn args [ '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-f',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   'make',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-I',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/config.gypi',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-I',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-I',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/8.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/8.17.0',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/myusername/.cache/node-gyp/8.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   'build',
     [exec] gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
     [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
     [exec]   File \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py\", line 47, in <module>
     [exec]     import gyp
     [exec]   File \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py\", line 10, in <module>
     [exec]     import gyp.input
     [exec]   File \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py\", line 9, in <module>
     [exec]     import gyp.common
     [exec]   File \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/common.py\", line 499, in <module>
     [exec]     class OrderedSet(collections.MutableSet):
     [exec]                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     [exec] AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSet'
     [exec] gyp ERR! configure error 
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
     [exec] gyp ERR! System Linux 6.3.6-arch1-1
     [exec] gyp ERR! command \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node\" \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"configure\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release/nodejieba.node\" \"--module_name=nodejieba\" \"--module_path=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\" \"--napi_build_version=0\" \"--node_napi_label=node-v57\"
     [exec] gyp ERR! cwd /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba
     [exec] gyp ERR! node -v v8.17.0
     [exec] gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
     [exec] gyp ERR! not ok 
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node /home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release/nodejieba.node --module_name=nodejieba --module_path=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v57' (1)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.cmd.on (/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 6.3.6-arch1-1
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node\" \"/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.17.0
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
     [exec] node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
     [exec] Failed to execute '/home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node /home/myusername/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release/nodejieba.node --module_name=nodejieba --module_path=/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/lib/quarto/node_modules/nodejieba/build/Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v57' (1)"

BUILD FAILED
/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/build.xml:173: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2023.03.2-454/src/gwt/build.xml:132: exec returned: 1

Total time: 31 seconds
make[2]: *** [src/gwt/CMakeFiles/gwt_build.dir/build.make:2672: src/gwt/timestamp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:412: src/gwt/CMakeFiles/gwt_build.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/pamac-build-myusername/rstudio-desktop/src/build'
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
```

Answer (score 1):

Building rstudio is a rather tedious and expensive process, especially if you have an underpowered system; if you don't have special needs such as custom optimisations, the `rstudio-desktop-bin` can be used instead. Most major AUR packages are also available as binary packages with a `-bin` suffix.